# MySQL pull data from same table, SUM multiple columns with conditions

Tags: mysql, select

I have created a users table that holds names and phone numbers (users).

```
id| name  | phone

1 | Frank | 0345221234
2 | Sara  | 0342555939
```

I got another table that holds a log with user's calls to different numbers (call_logs):

```
number     | destination | price

0345221234 | destination | x             /// This is Frank
0345221234 | destination | y             /// This is also Frank
0342555939 | destination | z             /// This is Sara
```

And then I have a table that holds numbers that Frank and Sara are allowed to call (allowed_numbers):

```
number

033485733
045727728
082358288
```

I would like to loop through my users table and based on their number to check the calls log table and select the `SUM` of `price` column for log records where `destination` does not match the allowed numbers table so that I know the cost for calls not in the allowed list.

Then I want to select `SUM` of `price` column for log records where `destination` DO match
the allowed numbers table so that I know how much did the allowed calls cost.

Is there any way I can do this in a single query with sub-queries and all needed in order to achieve this result set:

```
users number | SUM(price) of allowed calls | SUM(price) of calls not allowed
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us explicitly what the table names are? I'm assuming `users`, `call_logs`, `allowed_numbers` with a high probability of being wrong.

Comment: Right, sorry, edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT call_logs.number
  ,SUM(IF(allowed_numbers.number IS NOT NULL,call_logs.price,0)) AS AllowedPrice
  ,SUM(IF(allowed_numbers.number IS NULL,call_logs.price,0)) AS NotAllowedPrice
FROM call_logs
LEFT JOIN allowed_numbers
  ON call_logs.destination = allowed_numbers.number
GROUP BY call_logs.number;
```

Comment: It looks great! Are there any ways to SUM another field from the logs table? Like duration field for each allowed conversations and not allowed ones. Thanks!

Comment: @MannyCalavera - You can continue to add additional fields to the SELECT clause like `SUM(call_logs.duration)` or `SUM(IF(allowed_numbers.number IS NULL,call_logs.duration,0))`